# PHP Logic - If conditions are true, do nothing

Tags: php, logic

What's the best way to say: if conditions are true, do nothing?

```
if ($fromDate >= $rangeEnd || $toDate < $rangeStart) {
    // In both cases we are Out of Range, so do nothing...
} else {
   // We are in Range...do something
}
```

Comment: mmm...`if !($fromDate....)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to write a "do nothing" case isn't a good practice. I'd check for the opposite condition and use that block to run the code, i.e. negate the condition and remove the `else` block:

```
if ( !($fromDate >= $rangeEnd || $toDate < $rangeStart) ) {
    // We are in Range...do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Negate it :-) or build the condition differently!

```
if($fromDate < $rangeEnd || $toDate > $rangeStart) {
  // Do something
}

// Nothing to do here... :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your statement.

```
if ($fromDate < $rangeEnd || $toDate > $rangeStart) {
   // We are in Range...do something
}
```

nOtice the >= and < have been changed